# How to get the count of unique SKU per Date, in a table in mysql (Self learning question)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My current Data Set, I haven't touched mysql in a while so this is not clicking in my brain.

What I have is this, which has SKU and Date which it was sold

```
##SKU,  DateSold
'12',   '1-Jan-08' 
'12',   '1-Jan-08' 
'11',   '1-Jan-08' 
'11',   '2-Jan-08' 
'11',   '2-Jan-08' 
'11',   '3-Jan-08' 
'13',   '3-Jan-08' 
'11',   '4-Jan-08' 
'13',   '5-Jan-08'
```

What I want is this

```
##SKU, COUNT, DateSold
12,     2,      1-Jan-08 
11,     1,      1-Jan-08 
11,     2,      2-Jan-08 
11,     1,      3-Jan-08 
13,     1,      3-Jan-08 
11,     1,      4-Jan-08 
13,     1,      5-Jan-08
```

This is not for an assignment, this for my personal understanding of mysql in prep for better coding skills.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not too hard to make it in a query.

I understand that you are a beginner i guess.

Do it like this:

```
SELECT SKU,count(1) as Count,DateSold from yourTable GROUP BY SKU,DateSold ORDER BY datesold
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to use your query as well, I was playing around and came up wit this                                                 
 `SELECT SKU,COUNT(*) as Count,Date FROM table GROUP BY SKU,Date; `

Comment: Welcome. If this solution helped your problem then you can mark it as answered.

Comment: I am currently looking up why COUNT(1) was used instead of the COUNT(*)

Comment: Don't be confused it's all the same.