# Self Learn question mysql, How to use 2 tables to create a 3rd table that uses the information on the original 2 tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, data-science

I asked an earlier question that helped me creating this table below
[How to get the count of unique SKU per Date, in a table in mysql (Self learning question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174554/how-to-get-the-count-of-unique-sku-per-date-in-a-table-in-mysql-self-learning/54174734#54174734)

```
SKU, COUNT, DateSold
12,     2,      1-Jan-08 
11,     1,      1-Jan-08 
11,     2,      2-Jan-08 
11,     1,      3-Jan-08 
13,     1,      3-Jan-08 
11,     1,      4-Jan-08 
13,     1,      5-Jan-08
```

Using this existing table above and

SKU Price table below

```
SKU, PRICE
11,     5.00
12,    10.00
13,    15.00
```

Now the question is how can I use these 2 tables to create Total per each day without doing it manually, Below is my desired TABLE.

```
Day,       Total
1-Jan-08,    25.00
2-Jan-08,    10.00
3-Jan-08,    20.00
4-Jan-08,    05.00
5-Jan-08,    15.00
```

I have some thing like this in a excel file I created (Pivot table) but I am hoping mysql can help me do this efficiently and faster. Again I am new to this and it would help me lot to understand sql. This is not not an assignment this again me trying to upgrade my skills.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you start from the sales data from your original question, you can get the results you want by `JOIN`ing that table to your `price` table (to get the price of each item) and then just summing the `PRICE` of each item sold (since there is only one item per row). We `GROUP BY Day` to get the results on a daily basis:

```
SELECT s.DateSold AS Day, SUM(p.PRICE) AS Total
FROM sales s
JOIN price p ON p.SKU = s.SKU
GROUP BY Day
```

If you want to start from your already aggregated data, you would change the query somewhat. In this case you have a `COUNT` of items sold each day, so you have to `SUM` that count multiplied by the price of the item.

```
SELECT d.DateSold AS Day, SUM(d.COUNT * p.PRICE) AS Total
FROM daysales d
JOIN price p ON p.SKU = d.SKU
GROUP BY Day
```

Output (for both queries):

```
Day         Total
1-Jan-08    25
2-Jan-08    10
3-Jan-08    20
4-Jan-08    5
5-Jan-08    15
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7c7c3773a6202bf6d17bc960e501a680)

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried both ways and it does work ! Thank you for showing me dbfiddle as well. Awesome answer with clarity!

Comment: @AlphaBin no worries, I'm glad you found the answer helpful.